# How to lock my firefox extension on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, firefox, mobile

How can I lock my firefox extension on mobile devices?
I don't want to support them. How can I lock this? Somewhere in manifest.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you can do it on addons.mozilla.org when adding a plugin ;)